# importing theano on anaconda 3.10.0

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, theano

I'm trying to import theano and I'm using the anaconda version 3.10.0, Can anyone give me directions to how to proceed?

Thanks in advance

> Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below: g++
>   -shared -g -D NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -DMS_WIN64 -IC:\Users\Supreeth\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\Supreeth\Anaconda\include -o C:\Users\Supreeth\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:\Users\Supreeth\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp
>   -LC:\Users\Supreeth\Anaconda\libs -LC:\Users\Supreeth\Anaconda -lpython27

Comment: Can you please update your question with more details. For example, Are you following the documentation? http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html Which C++ compiler do you have installed? Are you trying to run on CPU or GPU? That error message appears to be truncated, can you paste the entire thing please?

Comment: That document link you have shared, solved my issue. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could post an answer to your own question so other people might benefit from what you've learnt? Answering ones own question is encouraged on StackOverflow if you solve the problem for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution from the [Theano Installation Document](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html)

> Specifically for Anaconda users just use the command

```
$ conda install mingw libpython
```

in the Anaconda Command Prompt

Comment: Just extra info, you should use the dev version of Theano on windows with anaconda (until theano 0.7.1 is released). It should link better with blas.